# Able to get rep artifically via migrated questions

Tags: bug, status-declined, voting, migration

A while back, I accidentally asked a question on Super User that should have gone on Stack Overflow. It got moved, but my accounts weren't linked, so it didn't show me as the owner of my question.

I was able to upvote it, and I discovered that after I linked my accounts I got the 10 rep points from my question and was unable to remove my vote.

Has this been seen before and can it be fixed?

Comment: Sounds like a cross site scripting bug. Does this mean that some of us might be able to reach Skeet's rep level some day via this *cough*cheat*cough*mechanism? ;)

Comment: I mean the "cross site scripting bug" as a pun. :)

Comment: It would be an *awful* lot of work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm really not sure it is worth worrying about; it is *such* an edge-case that you would get minimal rep. Arguably, posting on meta about some nuance of a question (with link) is a far more efficient rep exploit.

Actually, there is a known glitch at the moment when we merge two accounts for the same user; it is possible (in the nefarious cases) that those accounts have intentionally cross-voted each-other, and this doesn't *currently* get removed when merging.

My point (I'm getting there); I'm hopeful that Jeff/team will eventually fix the above to remove self-votes as a scheduled task; this would address the above (slightly-less-evil) case as a handy side-effect.